# Angularjs - Checkbox disabling and enabling

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looking for a way to do exactly opposite from this example that was taken from angularjs ng-disabled documentation ... http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngDisabled

In this example checking the box disables the button. I need exactly the opposite,,, I need the checked box to enable a disabled button. Can someone shed some light on this for me please.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Click me to toggle: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"><br/>
<button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="checked">Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do:

```
ng-disabled="!checked"
```

The `!` means to do the opposite, so `!true == false = true`

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ht0z3lTJi8EfPJEKWcWl?p=preview

Comment: Oh gosh!! I keep forgetting this thing is pretty flexible :) Thank you!

Comment: Baller assed answer bro. Nice.